discord bot timestamp delay issue
I have created a bot js command which every 5 seconds updates status on website whether it's online or not. Timestamp as well displays current time, but for some reason after some time it starts to get delayed by minute by two and then last you know it's delayed by hours. I think it's has something to do with those 5 seconds of status check.
const tcpp = require('tcp-ping');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

let statusMessage = null; 

module.exports = {
    checkWeb: async (client) => {
        try {
            const website = {
                name: "mysite",
                url: "mysite.com",
                port: 80 
            };

            tcpp.probe(website.url, website.port, function(err, available) {
                if (err) {
                    throw new Error(`Error probing website: ${err}`);
                }

                const status = available ? " Online" : " Offline";
                const color = available ? "#00FF00" : "#FF0000";
                const description = available ? `The ${website.url} is up and running.` : `The ${website.url} is offline.`;

                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle(`Status of ${website.name}`)
                    .setDescription(`${description}\n\nStatus: ${status}\n\u200B`)
                    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setColor(color);

                if (!statusMessage) {
                    client.channels.cache.get('1232582546932633610').send({ embeds: [embed] })
                        .then(message => {
                            statusMessage = message.id; 
                        });
                } else {
                    client.channels.cache.get('1232582546932633610').messages.fetch(statusMessage)
                        .then(message => {
                            message.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
                        })
                        .catch(console.error);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error checking website status: ${error}`);
        } finally {
            setTimeout(() => module.exports.checkWeb(client), 5 * 1000); 
        }
    }
};


These following scenarios can cause it to have delay issues.

Discord APIS have a rate limit to prevent abuse, so that you don't have a way to prevent the bot from breaking the limits.
In your code snippet, you’re using setTimeout to schedule the status update every 5 seconds, and JavaScript may introduce a slight delay.
And lastly Network latency can impact the response time.

